# Tracking Changes of Data Refresh from Sharepoint List In Excel

Tags: vba, excel, sharepoint, vbscript

I have a excel sheet that is is connected to sharepoint List as data source. Every time I refresh the entire table is updated. The List is saved in a table format.

How would it be possible to track changes of the updates that are made every time it updates? The Track changes tab is greyed out in the review tab. If I remove query definitions by converting table into range the 'track changes' appears again but my connection is no longer functional.

I want to be able to just see the updates that occur. Is there is a better way to visualize such changes ? I already have versioning on in the sharepoint but that is not what I want.

Comment: You want a list of every time the Excel worksheet recalculates?

Comment: You’d need to keep a copy of the previous data and compare that to the updated version

Comment: @TimWilliams how would you recommend to do that

Comment: @ashleedawg no i want to track changes that are made in the list after it updates

Comment: You'd have to write some VBA to do that.  If that's outside of your skill-set then it's the type of thing you could consider hiring someone to write for you.  Exactly how you might make the comparison would depend on what your data looks like.